# How do I send data to a newly created HTML page that will be displayed permanently?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on creating a forum system, and am currently trying to populate each forum with its threads and other data unique to that forum. I have a form that submits data to the database (the forum name, and a forum description), and then creates a new folder and index page for that forum, which looks like:

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/forum/$forumTitle");
$createdPage = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/forum/$forumTitle/index.php", "w") or die("error");
$content = file_get_contents("/template.php");
fwrite($createdPage, $content);
fclose($createdPage);
```

This works so far, but I want to know how I can pass the data that was sent to the database to the next page to be displayed permanently inside the HTML. For example:

```
<h1 class="forum-welcome">forum description goes here</h1>
```

Similar questions about passing data like this have answers that suggest using $_SESSION, but I would like this information to be visible even to users who are not logged into my website. Perhaps I'm going about this incorrectly and need to utilize my database to store these pages (right now I'm creating them as directories inside my main project folder).

Comment: That's a lot of potential issues down the road. You should consider only having the pages needed to dynamically generate all the forums, and use dynamic URL re-writes

Comment: Having PHP write other PHP files based on user input is not something I'd advise doing

Comment: I was going to employ a similar approach when allowing users to create threads. Should I therefore be storing everything I need in the database, and displaying the data from there?

Comment: The short answer: yes. The long answer: when using PHP, you should try and use the most minimal amount of files to get the job done. The language is dynamic for a reason, taking full advantage of that, you should be able to handle all the threads in 1 php file

Comment: @Dalsia Yes you should!

Comment: Alright, I very much appreciate the help. I was not sure which approach to take since I've never worked on the back end of a website, so I will try to figure out an approach using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @Dalsia You might want to look into using `Laravel`, as it kind of takes a lot of the hard architecture decisions and handles them for you